# X-Ray Cloud integration into JIRA changes the summary of existing Jira issues

Tags: python, robotframework, jira, jira-xray

I have built an app that creates an X-Ray execution based on the RobotFramework output.xml file using the X-Ray RESTful APIs. I understand that if I have a tag, such as QA-263, in my .robot script that doesn't exist in Jira, X-Ray will create a test for that tag. However, I don't understand why X-Ray is changing the summary for tests that already have a matching key.

This is problematic because we have a set of Jira issues and a library of .robot scripts that are virtually associated to the Test Cases via tags. Running and importing the results of a .robot script is changing the Jira summary of the Tests to "Test Start", for instance, which is the name of the first Test Case in some of our .robot files.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Bottom line is I don't want the Issue Summary to be changed when the import occurs. I would expect the Issue to just be associated to the created execution without modification.

Thanks for any assistance or information on this.

Comment: Are you using Xray on Jiara cloud or Xray on Jira server/datacenter?

Comment: @Sérgio we are using Jira Cloud.

Comment: Please check my answer,  and if you agree please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import process is non-configurable.
However, the behaviour that you reported is something that should not happen.
A [issue](https://jira.getxray.app/browse/XRAYCLOUD-4914) was added to the backlog reporting the current behavior and the expected one.
I would advise you to reach out to [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2), reporting also this so your issue is tracked properly (as it's the official support channel). You should mention the issue that was added in the backlog.